# How do I install drivers for AR9271 on Centos 6?

Tags: centos, drivers

I'm trying to get a USB wireless card that runs off of the AR9271 chipset to work with Centos 6.2.

I read this description for [compat-wireless](http://linuxwireless.org/en/users/Download) and wanted to use a package manager (i.e. yum) because I wanted a relatively easy uninstall if it didn't work. I found a package on [ELRepo](http://elrepo.org/tiki/tiki-index.php). I installed kmod-compat-wireless.i686 via `yum install` as root. After rebooting and sticking the USB wireless card in, I didn't see anything that indicated that wireless was working. What should I be looking for? How can I make sure that this driver is loaded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A rundown of my discovery process is here [at the Centos forums](https://www.centos.org/modules/newbb/viewtopic.php?topic_id=37243&forum=57).

**Helpful debugging tips**

Being relatively new to CentOS, (and by extension GNU/Linux), here are some commands I found helpful in troubleshooting hardware issues:

1. `lsusb` lists stuff that's connected via USB.
2. `lspci` lists stuff that's connected via PCI.
3. `lsmod` lists modules that are loaded.
4. `yum` has an awesome script that spits out your configuration to help others help you. The [directions are here](http://www.centos.org/modules/newbb/viewtopic.php?topic_id=28723&forum=54).
5. Check the dmesg log in '/var/log'. This is where I found the actual error message.

**Making AR9271 work**

1. Enable [El Repo](http://elrepo.org/tiki/) as a repository for yum.
2. `yum install kmod-compat-wireless` This installs the driver.
3. `wget -P /lib/firmware http://wireless.kernel.org/download/htc_fw/1.3/htc_9271.fw` This installs the correct firmware. This step may be unnecessary. The El Repo folks are figuring how to package the firmware so that it automatically gets pulled down in a kmod-compat-wireless install. So you may want to check if the htc file exists at `/lib/firmware/` before doing this step.
4. Reboot and a wireless option should appear in your Network Manager.